# print value in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I made a MIPS program to add two numbers stored in memory, and store the result in memory. Now I would like to print to video the value of result, but I don't know how. Here's my code :

```
.text
.globl main
main:
lw $t0, value1
lw $t1, value2
add $t2,$t0,$t1
sw $t2, result


.data
value1 : .word 23
value2 : .word 3
result : .word 0

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"print to video"_. But if you just want to print an integer to the console, then use [system call 1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) (assumes you're using a simulator like SPIM or MARS).

Comment: And of course that code executing system call 10 should be in the `.text` section (after the `sw`), not in the `.data` section.

Comment: ok thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines to print in mips. In this $t2 is the register which will going to be print.

```
move $a0, $t2     
li $v0, 1         # call number = print integer
syscall           # print integer ( $a0 )
```

Comment: thank you. And if I wanted to print a value stored in memory instead of the content of a register? I should load the value to a register and then print it or is there another way?

Comment: You want to print the variable result as u have stored value in variable 'result' .----
li $v0, 1
lw $a0, result        
syscall